# Define a $S_{m+n}$-module using induced modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Consider two Young diagrams $\lambda$ and $\mu$ with $|\lambda|=m$ and $|\mu|=n$. If $c_\lambda$ and $c_\mu$ are the corresponding Young symmetrizers, we define the $\mathbb{C}S_m$ resp. $\mathbb{C}S_n$-right modules $V_\lambda:=c_\lambda\mathbb{C}S_m$ resp. $V_\mu:=c_\mu\mathbb{C}S_n$.

The element $c_\lambda\otimes c_\mu $ can be identified as an element in $\mathbb{C}S_{m+n}$ and hence we get an right $S_{m+n}$ module $V_\lambda\cdot V_\mu :=c_\lambda\otimes c_\mu\mathbb{C}S_{m+n}$.

Can I write this module using the notion of induced modules?

Comment: This should be exactly the $S_m \times S_n$ module $V_\lambda \boxtimes V_\mu$ induced up to $S_{m + n}$. If you write out the definition of an induced module, this will be clear.

Comment: Can you write a few lines please? What is your definition of induced module? And what is $\boxtimes$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $G$ be a finite group, $H \leq G$ a subgroup, and $V$ a (right) $\mathbb{C}H$-module. Then the induced representation is defined as $$\mathrm{ind}_H^G V = V \otimes_{\mathbb{C}H} \mathbb{C}G$$

In your case, take $\lambda$ a partition of $m$, and define $V_\lambda = c_\lambda \mathbb{C}{S_m}$, where $S_m$ is thought of as permutations on the letters $\{1, \ldots, m\}$. Take also $\mu$ a partition of $n$, and define $V_\mu= c_\mu\mathbb{C}{S_n}$, where $S_n$ is thought of as permutations on the letters $\{m+1, \ldots, n+m\}$.

The product group $S_m \times S_n$ then acts on $V_\lambda \otimes V_\mu$ via $(g \times h) \cdot (v \otimes w) := gv \otimes hw$. Call this representation $V_\lambda \boxtimes V_\mu$, where $\boxtimes$ is pronounced "outer tensor". This is just notation that makes it clear we are gluing together different representations, with no interplay between them.

With the above descriptions, the group $S_m \times S_n$ is naturally a subgroup of $S_{m + n}$, and so we may form the induced module $W$:
$$ W = \mathrm{ind}_{S_m \times S_n}^{S_{m + n}} V_\lambda \boxtimes V_\mu = c_\lambda \mathbb{C}{S_m} \boxtimes c_\mu\mathbb{C}{S_n} \otimes_{\mathbb{C}S_m \times S_n} \mathbb{C}S_{n + m}$$

With that last description, you can see that everything to the left of the $\otimes_{S_{n + m}}$ could be pulled across to the right, leaving us with the space $1 \boxtimes 1 \otimes c_\lambda c_\mu \mathbb{C}S_{m + n} \cong c_\lambda c_\mu \mathbb{C}S_{m + n}$, which is what you were aiming at.